# Type does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, generics, swift, protocols

I'm still having trouble understanding some subtleties of generics in Swift. I define the following types:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int)
}

class ProtocolLabel : UILabel, SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int) {

    }
}

class ProtocolImageView : UIImageView, SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int) {
    }
}
```

viewForValue(2)
Now I defined the following function. I expect **T to be a UIView that conforms to protocol SomeProtocol**.

```
func viewForValue<T where T: SomeProtocol, T: UIView>(param: Int) -> UIView {
    var someView: T
    if param > 0 {
        someView = ProtocolLabel() as T
    } else {
        someView = ProtocolImageView() as T
    }
    someView.setValue(2)
    someView.frame = CGRectZero
    return someView
}
```

However, I'm getting the following compile error when I execute the code:

```
viewForValue(2) // <-- Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'SomeProtocol'
```

It seems that in the where clause I can't specify a class that does not implement the protocol. Why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try use this: <T where T: SomeProtocol, UIView>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewForValue` is supposed to return a class which inherits from `UIView` and implements `SomeProtocol`.
You have defined 2 classes having no direct relationship - they just inherit from `UIView` and implement `SomeProtocol`.

When the function has to determine the return type, the direct concrete type both classes inherit from is `UIView`, so that is what `viewForValue` returns.

In order to fix the problem, you have to create a direct and concrete relationship between the 2 classes, by creating a 3rd class inheriting from `UIView` and implementing `SomeProtocol`:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int)
}

class SomeClass: UIView, SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int) {

    }
}

class SomeSubclass : SomeClass {
}

class SomeOtherSubclass : SomeClass {
}

func viewForValue<T where T: SomeProtocol, T: SomeClass>(param: Int) -> T {
    var someView: T
    if param > 0 {
        someView = SomeSubclass() as T
    } else {
        someView = SomeOtherSubclass() as T
    }
    someView.setValue(2)
    someView.frame = CGRectZero
    return someView
}

viewForValue(2)
```

**Addendum**: reading the OP comment below, the purpose is to dynamically instantiate existing UIKit classes inheriting from `UIView`. So the proposed solution doesn't apply.

I think that extending `UIView` by implementing `SomeProtocol` *should* work:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int)
}

extension UIView : SomeProtocol {
    func setValue(value: Int) {
    }
}

func viewForValue<T where T: SomeProtocol, T: UIView>(param: Int) -> UIView {
    var someView: T
    if param > 0 {
        someView = UILabel() as T
    } else {
        someView = UIImageView() as T
    }
    someView.setValue(2)
    someView.frame = CGRectZero
    return someView
}
```

but it looks like there's a compiler bug. This code in a playground shows a message stating that:

> Communication with the playground service was interrupted unexpectedly.
>   The playground service "com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground" may have generated a crash log.

whereas in an iOS application compilation fails due to a segmentation fault 11.

Comment: I was trying to be more generic with my question but in my case the classes involved are existing `UIView` subclasses: `UILabel`, `UIImageView` so I can't make them inherit from a `SomeClass`. I'm going to edit to reflect that.

Comment: See addition to my answer - I think the 2nd solution should work, but the code makes the compiler crash...

Comment: it does compile but crashes too. But at least it makes sense.